# AVAudioPlayer: Simple sound not playing

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to figure out why sounds aren't playing in my app, so I created what I think is as simple an implementation as possible:

```
  NSError *error;
   NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"canary-trills" ofType:@"wav"];
  NSLog(@"string=%@", soundFilePath);
  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
  NSLog(@"URL=%@", url);
  AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                            initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
  [avPlayer prepareToPlay];
  BOOL success = [avPlayer play];
  NSLog(@"The sound %@ play", success ? @"did" : @"didn't");
```

Per the console, it looks like it finds the resource, creates the URL correctly.  Even the play call indicates success.  However, no sound play in the simulator nor the device.

Comment: It is an established fact that it just does't work in the simulator for some stupid reason.

Comment: and what kind of error are you getting returned via the "`error`" parameter that you passed into "`AVAudioPlayer`"?

Comment: NSLog(@"NSError=%@", error); prints NSError=(null)

Answer (score 2):

AVAudioPlayer wasn't being retained & was going out of scope.

Adding:
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

to the class & using that member solved the issue.

Comment: Damn it. 1 minute late. Correct answer, by the way.